# IE7 CSS Horizontal Space Issue

Tags: html, css

I have a CSS top-margin issue for a SlideShow Photo within IE7 only.

I cant locate the problem with the CSS.

http://www.davincispainting.com/default.aspx

In IE7- for some reason the SlideShow Photo does NOT have a top-margin.

[image]

In IE8- the SlideShow Photo does have normal top-margin:

[image]

Comment: Try padding instead of margin. I looked at your markup - it won't make a difference whether you use margin or padding.

Comment: @Scott which class specifically for Padding?  There are several in this instance.

Comment: I think he means - try padding-top:12px for #top-feature instead of the current margin-top 12px (the margin: 12px 0 0 17px)

Comment: @Scott I think that solved the problem, but why does this exist only for IE7?

Comment: With IE, sometimes you just have to experiment. For example, if you have cleaning on a div that has margin at the top, the margin won't be respected by IE. I didn't look that closely at the css, but that could be the case here. I'll add my comment as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try padding instead of margin. I looked at your markup - it won't make a difference whether you use margin or padding.

(see comments above)

Further, in a lot of cases I don't bother trying to remember the different browser intricacies with IE. If I see space that shouldn't exist, I'll try to remove whitespace from my markup or use display:block. If there is not space that should be there, I'll switch from margin to padding (if possible).

I'm sure someone on here can give you a better answer, but this works for me in most cases.